# Find all functions that are analytic on the closed disk and that satisfy

Tags: complex-analysis

I got these questions incorrect on an old exam because I wasn't really sure where to go after applying Liouville.

1. Find all functions that are analytic on a closed disk of radius 4 centered at the origin and that satisfy $f(z) = 8$ for all $z$ on the circle $|z| = 4$.
2. Find all entire functions $f$ that satisfy the condition $|f(z)| ≤ \sqrt{|z|}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

I know I'm supposed to show that the function is bounded and entire, but am not really sure where to go from there. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Hints: (1) What do you know about an analytic function that is constant on a set of points with a limit point?
(2) Look at the Cauchy Integral Formula, specifically at the so-called Cauchy estimates. What can you conclude about $f^{(n)}(0)$ for all $n$?

Comment: Nice hints! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

(1) Using maximum principle for the real part of $f$, which is harmonic function, helps.
 (2) by Picard's theorem an entire function that misses three points in its range is constant.

Comment: I don't see how Picard's theorem applies.

Comment: Well, one can apply it to the function $f(z)/\sqrt(z)$, which is bounded and entire. The singularity at $0$ is removable...

Comment: Daved: I don't see how an application of Picard's theorem is needed in your comment, which would lend itself more readily to Liouville's theorem.  A problem with the argument in the comment as far as I understand is that there is no continuous branch of the square root function on $\mathbb C$, so no reason why $f(z)/\sqrt z$ would be entire without knowing apriori that $f\equiv 0$.  Using the notion of removable singularity, however, one method is to show that the singularity at $\infty$ is removable, which then implies that the function is constant by Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Sorry, one should apply my argument to $f^2(z)/z$, which is bounded and entire, and therefore, constant by Liouville's or Picard's theorem. Then, since $f(z)$ has no branch cut, the constant must be $0$.